# sed script delete line before if blank line

Tags: regex, linux, sed

I have a file that looks like this:

```
name:height:weight

janice:120:209
mark:150:349
ray:90:204
elle:140:129

----------
```

I want to write a sed script that adds a line containing `~` at the beginning + end of the file and before and after every person entry, like this:

```
~
name:height:weight

~
janice:120:209
~
mark:150:349
~
ray:90:204
~
elle:140:129
~

----------
~
```

My current script and output look like this, but I dont know how I can add '~' between every person entry:

```
1i ~
$a ~
```

```
~
name:height:weight

janice:120:209
mark:150:349
ray:90:204
elle:140:129

----------
~
```

Comment: So...you want to add a line containing `~` at the end of the file and before every non-blank line unless that line exactly matches `--------`?  Rather than just giving sample desired output, try describing what it is you are trying to do.

Comment: @WilliamPursell sorry for the confusion, I edited my question!

Comment: sed is the best tool for doing s/old/new/ on single lines. That's not what you're trying to do so you shouldn't be trying to use sed for it as there are better-suited tools, e.g. awk.

Answer (score 2):

This doesn't exactly match your output, but it does match what I described in the comment and which you confirmed is what you want:

```
awk '/./ && !/^---/{print "~"}1; END{print "~"}' input
```

Tweak as needed depending on your actual requirements.

Comment: Thanks for your response! I was wondering how I could do this with a sed script instead of awk

Comment: @j.doe the sed constructs to do anything like that will be non-portable, inefficient, arcane, and became obsolete 40+ years ago when awk was invented.

Answer (score 0):

Probably the shortest answer among all those:

Sed script:

```
i ~
/^name:height:weight$\|^$/N
$a ~
```

Explanation:

- Line 1: insert `~` before each line
- Line 2: if we hit the header or the empty line before `--------`
  we skip the next `~`
- Line 3: append `~` to the end of the stream

Let's save it `script.sed`, and test it out:

```
> sed -f script.sed test.txt
~
name:height:weight

~
janice:120:209
~
mark:150:349
~
ray:90:204
~
elle:140:129
~

----------
~
```

Tested with

```
> sed --version
sed (GNU sed) 4.2.2
Copyright (C) 2012 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
License GPLv3+: GNU GPL version 3 or later <http://gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html>.
This is free software: you are free to change and redistribute it.
There is NO WARRANTY, to the extent permitted by law.

Written by Jay Fenlason, Tom Lord, Ken Pizzini,
and Paolo Bonzini.
GNU sed home page: <http://www.gnu.org/software/sed/>.
General help using GNU software: <http://www.gnu.org/gethelp/>.
E-mail bug reports to: <bug-sed@gnu.org>.
Be sure to include the word ``sed'' somewhere in the ``Subject:'' field.
```

Comment: Thank you for your response! The output is close to what I am looking for, and. (from the output of this command) I was wondering how I could remove the '~' under the 'name:height:weight' line and add the '~' above the 'janice:120:209' line

Comment: See the updates. This version misses the last `~`, but I guess it'll be easy to add.

Comment: For the new revision, I was wondering how I can add a '~' under the 'elle' line and remove the '~' before the '----' line

Comment: I am hoping to add a '~' before and after each person entry, and also add a '~' at the beginning and end of the script

Comment: You should mention which sed version will be required for those scripts since they won't work with a POSIX sed.

Comment: @j.doe came up with a short answer, and it's inspired by your question!

Answer (score 0):

This will work using any awk in any shell on every UNIX box:

```
$ cat tst.awk
BEGIN { RS="" }
NR == 1 { print "~\n" $0 "\n"; next }
/^-+$/  { print $0 "\n~"; next }
{
    gsub(/\n/,"\n~\n")
    print "~\n" $0 "\n~\n"
}
```

.

```
$ awk -f tst.awk file
~
name:height:weight

~
janice:120:209
~
mark:150:349
~
ray:90:204
~
elle:140:129
~

----------
~
```

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed -zE 's/.*/~\n&/mg;s/~\n//2;s/(.*)~\n(.*~)/\1\2/' file
```

Puts `~\n` above and below all non-empty lines, then removes the second and second from last occurrences of `~\n`.

Alternative:

```
sed -e '1i~' -e '1b;N;/^\n$/!a~' -e 'P;D' file
```